# Is there an OpenSSL command that checks the validity of a .p8 certificate

Tags: openssl, pusher

I've converted my certificate's extension apns-dev.pem to an apns-dev-output.p8 by running the following command:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in apns-dev.pem -out apns-dev-output.p8  -nocrypt
```

This works just fine and the file gets created.

What I'm looking for is a command similar to this one (This actually proves that this .pem file is valid):

```
openssl x509 -in apns-dev.pem  -text -noout
```

Is there any similar command that I can try on .p8 files.

I'm doing this so that I can upload my "signing key" to pusher. Currently I'm getting "the given APNs Signing Key file is not valid".

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
% openssl pkcs8 -in whatever.example.com.p8 -inform PEM -outform PEM > /dev/null
Enter Password: xxxxxxxxxxxx
% echo $?
0
```

In your Pusher case (which I've never used): what might be happening is that the uploaded key needs to be unencrypted or encrypted in a certain way.  Testing with an unencrypted key is easy.  For the latter situation, you'll need to read the Pusher docs to figure out what encryption algorithm they're expecting.